# How to limit characters per message and make anti-spam?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have this shouwbox script.
I would like to know how to limit the characters for each message like 70 characters.
And i would also like to know how to do so you have to wait 3 seconds between each message you post.

Here is my script.

**Index.html**

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>jQuery</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #daddy-shoutbox {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    width: 250px;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    }
    .shoutbox-list {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
    display: none;
    }
    #daddy-shoutbox-list {
      text-align: left;
      margin: 0px auto;
    }
    #daddy-shoutbox-form {
      text-align: left;

    }
    .shoutbox-list-time {
    color: #000;
    }
    .shoutbox-list-nick {
      margin-left: 5px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .shoutbox-list-message {
      margin-left: 5px;
    }

  </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>


  <div id="daddy-shoutbox">   
  <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">

<form id="daddy-shoutbox-form" action="demos/jquery-shoutbox/daddy-shoutbox.php?action=add" method="post"> 
  <tr> 
  <td>    
    Name: 
    <input type="text" name="nickname" /> 
  </td>
  </tr>
    <tr> 
  <td> 
  Message: 
  <input type="text" name="message" />
 <br /> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <span id="daddy-shoutbox-response"></span>
  </form> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
    <hr size="1" noshade />
    <div id="daddy-shoutbox-list"></div>
    <br />

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        var count = 0;
        var files = 'demos/jquery-shoutbox/';
        var lastTime = 0;

        function prepare(response) {
          var d = new Date();
          count++;
          d.setTime(response.time*1000);
          var mytime = d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes()+':'+d.getSeconds();
          var string = '<div class="shoutbox-list" id="list-'+count+'">'
              + '<span class="shoutbox-list-time">'+mytime+'</span>'
              + '<span class="shoutbox-list-nick">'+response.nickname+':</span>'
              + '<span class="shoutbox-list-message">'+response.message+'</span>'
              +'</div>';
          if (count > 11) { x = (count - 11); $('#list-' + x).fadeOut('slow'); x = document.getElementById('list-' + x); x.style.display = "none"; }
          return string;
        }

        function success(response, status)  { 
          if(status == 'success') {
            lastTime = response.time;
            $('#daddy-shoutbox-response').html('<img src="'+files+'images/accept.png" />');
            $('#daddy-shoutbox-list').prepend(prepare(response));
            $('input[@name=message]').attr('value', '').focus();
            $('#list-'+count).fadeIn('slow');
            timeoutID = setTimeout(refresh, 3000);
          }
        }

        function validate(formData, jqForm, options) {
          for (var i=0; i < formData.length; i++) { 
              if (!formData[i].value) {
                  alert('Please fill in all the fields'); 
                  $('input[@name='+formData[i].name+']').css('background', 'red');
                  return false; 
              } 
          } 
          $('#daddy-shoutbox-response').html('<img src="'+files+'images/loader.gif" />');
          clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        }

        function refresh() {
          $.getJSON(files+"daddy-shoutbox.php?action=view&time="+lastTime, function(json) {
            if(json.length) {
              for(i=0; i < json.length; i++) {
                $('#daddy-shoutbox-list').prepend(prepare(json[i]));
                $('#list-' + count).fadeIn('slow');
              }
              var j = i-1;
              lastTime = json[j].time;
            }
            //alert(lastTime);
          });
          timeoutID = setTimeout(refresh, 3000);
        }

        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            var options = { 
              dataType:       'json',
              beforeSubmit:   validate,
              success:        success
            }; 
            $('#daddy-shoutbox-form').ajaxForm(options);
            timeoutID = setTimeout(refresh, 100);
        });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**daddy-shoutbox.php**

```
<?php
  function replace(&$item, $key) {
    $item = str_replace('|', '-', $item);
  }

  if (!function_exists('file_put_contents')) {
        function file_put_contents($fileName, $data) {
            if (is_array($data)) {
                $data = join('', $data);
            }
            $res = @fopen($fileName, 'w+b');
            if ($res) {
                $write = @fwrite($res, $data);
                if($write === false) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return $write;
                }
            }
        }
    }

  //file_put_contents('debug.txt', print_r($_GET, true));
  switch($_GET['action']) {
    case 'add':
      array_walk($_POST, 'replace');
      $arr = file('messages.txt');

      if(count($arr) > 10)
        array_shift($arr);

      $_POST['nickname'] = htmlentities($_POST['nickname']);
      $_POST['message'] = htmlentities($_POST['message']);
      $time = time();
      $arr[] = $time.'|'.$_POST['nickname'].'|'.$_POST['message'].'|'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n";
      file_put_contents('messages.txt', implode('', $arr));

      $data['response'] = 'Good work';
      $data['nickname'] = $_POST['nickname'];
      $data['message'] = $_POST['message'];
      $data['time'] = $time;
    break;

    case 'view':
      $data = array();
      $arr = file('messages.txt');
      if(!$_GET['time'])
        $_GET['time'] = 0;
      foreach($arr as $row) {
        $aTemp = null;
        list($aTemp['time'], $aTemp['nickname'], $aTemp['message']) = explode('|', $row); 
        if($aTemp['message'] AND $aTemp['time'] > $_GET['time'])
          $data[] = $aTemp;
      }
      //file_put_contents('debug.txt', print_r($data, true));
    break;
  }

  require_once('JSON.php');
  $json = new Services_JSON();
  $out = $json->encode($data);
  print $out;
?>
```

**JSON.php**

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4: */

/**
 * Converts to and from JSON format.
 *
 * JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange
 * format. It is easy for humans to read and write. It is easy for machines
 * to parse and generate. It is based on a subset of the JavaScript
 * Programming Language, Standard ECMA-262 3rd Edition - December 1999.
 * This feature can also be found in  Python. JSON is a text format that is
 * completely language independent but uses conventions that are familiar
 * to programmers of the C-family of languages, including C, C++, C#, Java,
 * JavaScript, Perl, TCL, and many others. These properties make JSON an
 * ideal data-interchange language.
 *
 * This package provides a simple encoder and decoder for JSON notation. It
 * is intended for use with client-side Javascript applications that make
 * use of HTTPRequest to perform server communication functions - data can
 * be encoded into JSON notation for use in a client-side javascript, or
 * decoded from incoming Javascript requests. JSON format is native to
 * Javascript, and can be directly eval()'ed with no further parsing
 * overhead
 *
 * All strings should be in ASCII or UTF-8 format!
 *
 * LICENSE: Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or
 * without modification, are permitted provided that the following
 * conditions are met: Redistributions of source code must retain the
 * above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following
 * disclaimer. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above
 * copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer
 * in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
 * distribution.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED ``AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED
 * WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN
 * NO EVENT SHALL CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
 * INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
 * BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS
 * OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
 * ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR
 * TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE
 * USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH
 * DAMAGE.
 *
 * @category
 * @package     Services_JSON
 * @author      Michal Migurski <mike-json@teczno.com>
 * @author      Matt Knapp <mdknapp[at]gmail[dot]com>
 * @author      Brett Stimmerman <brettstimmerman[at]gmail[dot]com>
 * @copyright   2005 Michal Migurski
 * @version     CVS: $Id: JSON.php,v 1.31 2006/06/28 05:54:17 migurski Exp $
 * @license     http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php
 * @link        http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=198
 */

/**
 * Marker constant for Services_JSON::decode(), used to flag stack state
 */
define('SERVICES_JSON_SLICE',   1);

/**
 * Marker constant for Services_JSON::decode(), used to flag stack state
 */
define('SERVICES_JSON_IN_STR',  2);

/**
 * Marker constant for Services_JSON::decode(), used to flag stack state
 */
define('SERVICES_JSON_IN_ARR',  3);

/**
 * Marker constant for Services_JSON::decode(), used to flag stack state
 */
define('SERVICES_JSON_IN_OBJ',  4);

/**
 * Marker constant for Services_JSON::decode(), used to flag stack state
 */
define('SERVICES_JSON_IN_CMT', 5);

/**
 * Behavior switch for Services_JSON::decode()
 */
define('SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE', 16);

/**
 * Behavior switch for Services_JSON::decode()
 */
define('SERVICES_JSON_SUPPRESS_ERRORS', 32);

/**
 * Converts to and from JSON format.
 *
 * Brief example of use:
 *
 * <code>
 * // create a new instance of Services_JSON
 * $json = new Services_JSON();
 *
 * // convert a complexe value to JSON notation, and send it to the browser
 * $value = array('foo', 'bar', array(1, 2, 'baz'), array(3, array(4)));
 * $output = $json->encode($value);
 *
 * print($output);
 * // prints: ["foo","bar",[1,2,"baz"],[3,[4]]]
 *
 * // accept incoming POST data, assumed to be in JSON notation
 * $input = file_get_contents('php://input', 1000000);
 * $value = $json->decode($input);
 * </code>
 */
class Services_JSON
{
   /**
    * constructs a new JSON instance
    *
    * @param    int     $use    object behavior flags; combine with boolean-OR
    *
    *                           possible values:
    *                           - SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE:  loose typing.
    *                                   "{...}" syntax creates associative arrays
    *                                   instead of objects in decode().
    *                           - SERVICES_JSON_SUPPRESS_ERRORS:  error suppression.
    *                                   Values which can't be encoded (e.g. resources)
    *                                   appear as NULL instead of throwing errors.
    *                                   By default, a deeply-nested resource will
    *                                   bubble up with an error, so all return values
    *                                   from encode() should be checked with isError()
    */
    function Services_JSON($use = 0)
    {
        $this->use = $use;
    }

   /**
    * convert a string from one UTF-16 char to one UTF-8 char
    *
    * Normally should be handled by mb_convert_encoding, but
    * provides a slower PHP-only method for installations
    * that lack the multibye string extension.
    *
    * @param    string  $utf16  UTF-16 character
    * @return   string  UTF-8 character
    * @access   private
    */
    function utf162utf8($utf16)
    {
        // oh please oh please oh please oh please oh please
        if(function_exists('mb_convert_encoding')) {
            return mb_convert_encoding($utf16, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');
        }

        $bytes = (ord($utf16{0}) << 8) | ord($utf16{1});

        switch(true) {
            case ((0x7F & $bytes) == $bytes):
                // this case should never be reached, because we are in ASCII range
                // see: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                return chr(0x7F & $bytes);

            case (0x07FF & $bytes) == $bytes:
                // return a 2-byte UTF-8 character
                // see: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                return chr(0xC0 | (($bytes >> 6) & 0x1F))
                     . chr(0x80 | ($bytes & 0x3F));

            case (0xFFFF & $bytes) == $bytes:
                // return a 3-byte UTF-8 character
                // see: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                return chr(0xE0 | (($bytes >> 12) & 0x0F))
                     . chr(0x80 | (($bytes >> 6) & 0x3F))
                     . chr(0x80 | ($bytes & 0x3F));
        }

        // ignoring UTF-32 for now, sorry
        return '';
    }

   /**
    * convert a string from one UTF-8 char to one UTF-16 char
    *
    * Normally should be handled by mb_convert_encoding, but
    * provides a slower PHP-only method for installations
    * that lack the multibye string extension.
    *
    * @param    string  $utf8   UTF-8 character
    * @return   string  UTF-16 character
    * @access   private
    */
    function utf82utf16($utf8)
    {
        // oh please oh please oh please oh please oh please
        if(function_exists('mb_convert_encoding')) {
            return mb_convert_encoding($utf8, 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8');
        }

        switch(strlen($utf8)) {
            case 1:
                // this case should never be reached, because we are in ASCII range
                // see: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                return $utf8;

            case 2:
                // return a UTF-16 character from a 2-byte UTF-8 char
                // see: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                return chr(0x07 & (ord($utf8{0}) >> 2))
                     . chr((0xC0 & (ord($utf8{0}) << 6))
                         | (0x3F & ord($utf8{1})));

            case 3:
                // return a UTF-16 character from a 3-byte UTF-8 char
                // see: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                return chr((0xF0 & (ord($utf8{0}) << 4))
                         | (0x0F & (ord($utf8{1}) >> 2)))
                     . chr((0xC0 & (ord($utf8{1}) << 6))
                         | (0x7F & ord($utf8{2})));
        }

        // ignoring UTF-32 for now, sorry
        return '';
    }

   /**
    * encodes an arbitrary variable into JSON format
    *
    * @param    mixed   $var    any number, boolean, string, array, or object to be encoded.
    *                           see argument 1 to Services_JSON() above for array-parsing behavior.
    *                           if var is a strng, note that encode() always expects it
    *                           to be in ASCII or UTF-8 format!
    *
    * @return   mixed   JSON string representation of input var or an error if a problem occurs
    * @access   public
    */
    function encode($var)
    {
        switch (gettype($var)) {
            case 'boolean':
                return $var ? 'true' : 'false';

            case 'NULL':
                return 'null';

            case 'integer':
                return (int) $var;

            case 'double':
            case 'float':
                return (float) $var;

            case 'string':
                // STRINGS ARE EXPECTED TO BE IN ASCII OR UTF-8 FORMAT
                $ascii = '';
                $strlen_var = strlen($var);

               /*
                * Iterate over every character in the string,
                * escaping with a slash or encoding to UTF-8 where necessary
                */
                for ($c = 0; $c < $strlen_var; ++$c) {

                    $ord_var_c = ord($var{$c});

                    switch (true) {
                        case $ord_var_c == 0x08:
                            $ascii .= '\b';
                            break;
                        case $ord_var_c == 0x09:
                            $ascii .= '\t';
                            break;
                        case $ord_var_c == 0x0A:
                            $ascii .= '\n';
                            break;
                        case $ord_var_c == 0x0C:
                            $ascii .= '\f';
                            break;
                        case $ord_var_c == 0x0D:
                            $ascii .= '\r';
                            break;

                        case $ord_var_c == 0x22:
                        case $ord_var_c == 0x2F:
                        case $ord_var_c == 0x5C:
                            // double quote, slash, slosh
                            $ascii .= '\\'.$var{$c};
                            break;

                        case (($ord_var_c >= 0x20) && ($ord_var_c <= 0x7F)):
                            // characters U-00000000 - U-0000007F (same as ASCII)
                            $ascii .= $var{$c};
                            break;

                        case (($ord_var_c & 0xE0) == 0xC0):
                            // characters U-00000080 - U-000007FF, mask 110XXXXX
                            // see http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                            $char = pack('C*', $ord_var_c, ord($var{$c + 1}));
                            $c += 1;
                            $utf16 = $this->utf82utf16($char);
                            $ascii .= sprintf('\u%04s', bin2hex($utf16));
                            break;

                        case (($ord_var_c & 0xF0) == 0xE0):
                            // characters U-00000800 - U-0000FFFF, mask 1110XXXX
                            // see http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                            $char = pack('C*', $ord_var_c,
                                         ord($var{$c + 1}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 2}));
                            $c += 2;
                            $utf16 = $this->utf82utf16($char);
                            $ascii .= sprintf('\u%04s', bin2hex($utf16));
                            break;

                        case (($ord_var_c & 0xF8) == 0xF0):
                            // characters U-00010000 - U-001FFFFF, mask 11110XXX
                            // see http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                            $char = pack('C*', $ord_var_c,
                                         ord($var{$c + 1}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 2}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 3}));
                            $c += 3;
                            $utf16 = $this->utf82utf16($char);
                            $ascii .= sprintf('\u%04s', bin2hex($utf16));
                            break;

                        case (($ord_var_c & 0xFC) == 0xF8):
                            // characters U-00200000 - U-03FFFFFF, mask 111110XX
                            // see http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                            $char = pack('C*', $ord_var_c,
                                         ord($var{$c + 1}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 2}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 3}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 4}));
                            $c += 4;
                            $utf16 = $this->utf82utf16($char);
                            $ascii .= sprintf('\u%04s', bin2hex($utf16));
                            break;

                        case (($ord_var_c & 0xFE) == 0xFC):
                            // characters U-04000000 - U-7FFFFFFF, mask 1111110X
                            // see http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                            $char = pack('C*', $ord_var_c,
                                         ord($var{$c + 1}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 2}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 3}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 4}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 5}));
                            $c += 5;
                            $utf16 = $this->utf82utf16($char);
                            $ascii .= sprintf('\u%04s', bin2hex($utf16));
                            break;
                    }
                }

                return '"'.$ascii.'"';

            case 'array':
               /*
                * As per JSON spec if any array key is not an integer
                * we must treat the the whole array as an object. We
                * also try to catch a sparsely populated associative
                * array with numeric keys here because some JS engines
                * will create an array with empty indexes up to
                * max_index which can cause memory issues and because
                * the keys, which may be relevant, will be remapped
                * otherwise.
                *
                * As per the ECMA and JSON specification an object may
                * have any string as a property. Unfortunately due to
                * a hole in the ECMA specification if the key is a
                * ECMA reserved word or starts with a digit the
                * parameter is only accessible using ECMAScript's
                * bracket notation.
                */

                // treat as a JSON object
                if (is_array($var) && count($var) && (array_keys($var) !== range(0, sizeof($var) - 1))) {
                    $properties = array_map(array($this, 'name_value'),
                                            array_keys($var),
                                            array_values($var));

                    foreach($properties as $property) {
                        if(Services_JSON::isError($property)) {
                            return $property;
                        }
                    }

                    return '{' . join(',', $properties) . '}';
                }

                // treat it like a regular array
                $elements = array_map(array($this, 'encode'), $var);

                foreach($elements as $element) {
                    if(Services_JSON::isError($element)) {
                        return $element;
                    }
                }

                return '[' . join(',', $elements) . ']';

            case 'object':
                $vars = get_object_vars($var);

                $properties = array_map(array($this, 'name_value'),
                                        array_keys($vars),
                                        array_values($vars));

                foreach($properties as $property) {
                    if(Services_JSON::isError($property)) {
                        return $property;
                    }
                }

                return '{' . join(',', $properties) . '}';

            default:
                return ($this->use & SERVICES_JSON_SUPPRESS_ERRORS)
                    ? 'null'
                    : new Services_JSON_Error(gettype($var)." can not be encoded as JSON string");
        }
    }

   /**
    * array-walking function for use in generating JSON-formatted name-value pairs
    *
    * @param    string  $name   name of key to use
    * @param    mixed   $value  reference to an array element to be encoded
    *
    * @return   string  JSON-formatted name-value pair, like '"name":value'
    * @access   private
    */
    function name_value($name, $value)
    {
        $encoded_value = $this->encode($value);

        if(Services_JSON::isError($encoded_value)) {
            return $encoded_value;
        }

        return $this->encode(strval($name)) . ':' . $encoded_value;
    }

   /**
    * reduce a string by removing leading and trailing comments and whitespace
    *
    * @param    $str    string      string value to strip of comments and whitespace
    *
    * @return   string  string value stripped of comments and whitespace
    * @access   private
    */
    function reduce_string($str)
    {
        $str = preg_replace(array(

                // eliminate single line comments in '// ...' form
                '#^\s*//(.+)$#m',

                // eliminate multi-line comments in '/* ... */' form, at start of string
                '#^\s*/\*(.+)\*/#Us',

                // eliminate multi-line comments in '/* ... */' form, at end of string
                '#/\*(.+)\*/\s*$#Us'

            ), '', $str);

        // eliminate extraneous space
        return trim($str);
    }

   /**
    * decodes a JSON string into appropriate variable
    *
    * @param    string  $str    JSON-formatted string
    *
    * @return   mixed   number, boolean, string, array, or object
    *                   corresponding to given JSON input string.
    *                   See argument 1 to Services_JSON() above for object-output behavior.
    *                   Note that decode() always returns strings
    *                   in ASCII or UTF-8 format!
    * @access   public
    */
    function decode($str)
    {
        $str = $this->reduce_string($str);

        switch (strtolower($str)) {
            case 'true':
                return true;

            case 'false':
                return false;

            case 'null':
                return null;

            default:
                $m = array();

                if (is_numeric($str)) {
                    // Lookie-loo, it's a number

                    // This would work on its own, but I'm trying to be
                    // good about returning integers where appropriate:
                    // return (float)$str;

                    // Return float or int, as appropriate
                    return ((float)$str == (integer)$str)
                        ? (integer)$str
                        : (float)$str;

                } elseif (pre
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce these limitations on the client-side for speed purposes, but they need to be applied on the server side.  Otherwise, someone could download your form, remove the limitations, and use it without limitations.  You've given us the client-side code, so there's not much we can do to help you with what you've given us.

If your site doesn't impliment some sort of login system, it probably should.  This is the best way to identify who is doing what (so if they are doing something like spamming, you can make them stop).

Answer (score 0):

To limit the number of characters on the client side I believe `<input type="text" maxlength="70"`> should work.

You will need to enforce the limit server side using substr(). Otherwise it would be terribly easy to circumvent.
eg.
$message = substr($_REQUEST['message'], 0, 70);

Seeing as 3 seconds isn't a terribly long time, you could make it so the page takes 3 seconds to load. Not an elegant solution and easily bypassed by ANY hacker but it's a start. put this at the beginning of your document:
`<?php
  sleep(3);
?`>